# How to handle duplicate routes when exposing ApiControllers and ODataControllers?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi2 project that exposes an ApiController and an ODataController.  Unfortunately, the OData controller can be accessed through two URLs.  One is "api/Dogs" and the other is "odata/Dogs"  This happens because I call both MapHttpRoute and MapODataserviceRoute.  The "api/Dogs" one actually instantiates the controller, runs the Get method, but returns an HTTP 406 with a blank result.  I want the "api/Dogs" URI to return a 404 and not even run instantiate the controller and run the method at all.  What is the best way to do this?

So far I have come-up with 3 possible approaches, although I have only tried #1 so far.  I am looking for feedback before I go any further.
1) I could explicitly ignore the route with IgnoreRoute().
2) I could write a constraint for the MapHttpRoute() call that checks if the controller is an ODataController.  This is possible, but seems like it would involve reflection and is doable but a bit messy.
3) Eliminate the call to MapHttpRoute() and use attribute routing.  I haven't tried attribute routing yet: does this make sense?

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // I could explicitly ignore the route.
        //config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("RedundantRouteCuzOfOData", "api/Dogs");

        // Standard routing
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
        );

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Dog>("Dogs");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}

public class DogsController : ODataController
{
   protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   {
       base.Initialize(controllerContext);
       Console.WriteLine("DogsController Initialized");
   }

   TestEntities _ef;

   [EnableQuery]
   public IQueryable<Dog> Get()
   {
       return Get(null);
   }

   [EnableQuery]
   // [Queryable(PageSize=10)] <-- Deprecated in oData v3 in favor of EnableQuery, see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22
   public IQueryable<Dog> Get(Guid? kennelId)
   {
       // Yes: The constructor for the entities takes a string.  I know that is odd,
       // but it tells the EF which database to connect to.
       _ef = new TestEntities(kennelId == null ? null : kennelId.ToString());
       var results = _ef.Dogs;
       return (IQueryable<Dog>)results;
   }

   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
       _ef.Dispose();
       base.Dispose(disposing);
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi Moby, Could you show some source code of DogsController? I try to repro your issue. but found that the url "Api/Dogs" and "Odata/Dogs" can route to the same method. but "Api/Dogs" cannot return the result. the return code is 406.....Thanks a lot

Comment: Then you did repro it successfully.  :-) I updated the question to include more detail.  I too get an HTTP 406.  What I want is a 404, and for it to not run the method at all.  I wonder if anyone else using odata and regular webapi within one project?  Or am I the only one bothered by this "extra" API?

Comment: Does your first approach works? I try but fail~

Comment: IT gave me a 404, although it was slightly different from the 404 I get if I visit something random like api/xyz123.  What was the failure?